# Which brands and models of smartphones run Tor smoothly?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'd like to have your feedback on the brands and models of smartphones on which Tor is able to run smoothly.

Please feel free to discuss your experiences about how your smartphones run Tor.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I use a galaxy note 2.
With Tor and i2p on it, works without any issues.